# Is the code below well formed, in particular regarding aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions, strict-aliasing

The template function below is part of a sequence generator. Instead of manual shifts, I came up with the following union-based solution to make the operations more explicit. It works great on all the compilers tested. [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/zGEqWd7GK).

However despite working in practice, I am afraid there are aliasing rules that are being violated, which means it might not work in the future or in another compiler other than GCC and CLANG.

Strictly in view of the C++ standard: is the code below well formed? Does it incur in undefined behavior?

```cpp
template <int BITS>
uint64_t flog2(uint64_t num) {
    constexpr uint64_t MAXNUM = (uint64_t(1) << BITS);    
    if (num < MAXNUM) return num; 
    union FP {
        double dbl;
        struct {
            uint64_t man: 52;
            uint32_t exp: 11;
            uint32_t sign: 1;
        };
        struct {
            uint64_t xman: 52-BITS;
            uint32_t xexp: 11+BITS;
            uint32_t xsgn: 1;
        };
    };
    FP fp;
    fp.dbl = num;
    fp.exp -= 1023-1+BITS;
    return fp.xexp;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: writing one value of a union and reading another is UB.

Comment: *"or in another compiler other than GCC and CLANG"* It is known that Microsoft's compiler allocates the bit fields in a different order. "Implementation-defined", and all that.

Comment: @Raildex Reading another member of a union is intended to be supported in a few cases. (Not in that one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the program is syntactically ill-formed in ISO standard C++. Anonymous `struct` members are not standard C++ (in contrast to C). They are an extension. In ISO standard C++ the `struct` must be named and accessed through that name.

I'll ignore that for the rest of the answer and pretend you were accessing through such a name.

---

It is not an aliasing violation technically, but undefined behavior for reading an inactive member of the union object in

```
fp.exp -= 1023-1+BITS;
```

The types don't really matter for this (in contrast to aliasing). There is always only at most one active member of a union, which would the last one which was either explicitly created or written with a member access/assignment expression. In your case `fp.dbl = num;` means that `dbl` is the active member and the only one that may be read from.

There is one exception in the standard for accessing the common initial sequence of standard layout class type members of a union, in which case the non-active one may be accessed as if it was the active one. But even your two `struct {` members have a non-empty common initial sequence only for `BITS == 0`.

However, in practice compilers typically explicitly support this kind of type punning, probably already for C compatibility where it is allowed.

---

Of course, even setting all of this aside, the layout of bitfields and the representations of the involved types are completely implementation-defined and you can't expect this to be generally portable.

Comment: If the layout of bitfields are not respected, what happens to the millions of lines of C++ written to process networking packets? Say, the `iphdr`  or `ethdr` structs for example?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher It is not about being respected. A bit field `uint64_t man: 52;` only means that is is possible to access `man` as a member of type `uint64_t` which can store up to 52 bit wide integer values in it. It doesn't actually say anything about memory layout. That is added by the implementation. For example MSVC sometimes adds padding where GCC/Clang do not. You can't naively use code written for one with the other when relying on bit field layout, although by relying on it you probably have UB as I described anyway and that is even more implementation-dependent (e.g. endianess).

Comment: So you are saying that there is no cross-platform way to define in C++ a memory layout for a struct? That sounds like a huge limitation to me.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Member layout can't be forced in standard C++, but it is possible to nest subobjects at any location inside an `unsigned char`/`std::byte` array member and provide accessors. But you still have sizes, alignment requirements and bit representation of the types you store in there and that is also pretty much all implementation-defined. I don't think the ISO standard ever intended to specify behavior on that low level in a portable manner. It is only necessary for platform-specific interfaces or for optimization, which would also be implementation-dependent anyway.

Comment: I mean, the ISO standard got to the point to define memory access models, didn't they? Why is that C has it but C++ does not? I think this is  a pretty important issue to be carelessly left under UB.

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the standard these rules are?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Regarding bit fields, some details of what is unspecified/implementation-defined are different, but basically the same holds for C as well as. In C union type-punning is allowed, but resulting values are unspecified. The memory/object model of C++ is described in [basic.memobj](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj). You need to take it together with the individual sections in [expr](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr) for who it applies to any given expression. For bit fields see also [class.bit](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit). Unfortunately it isn't straight-forward to read.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Ah, and of course [class.union](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union) for behavior of unions.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Also, sorry, I didn't really mean "unspecified" above for C type punning. I meant that the the resulting values are in any case still implementation-defined because the representation of the fundamental types and memory layout of structs are also implementation-defined. However the resulting value may be a trap representation. (It is unspecified only when reading from padding.)

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour to read from a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) member that was not most recently written.

Furthermore, the layout of [bit-fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) is implementation-defined.

Hence, from a strict C++ Standard view, this code invokes both undefined behaviour (by reading `exp` after writing `dbl`) and relies on implementation-defined behaviour in assuming that the bit-field layout corresponds to the `double` floating point representation (which by the way is also implementation-defined).

Comment: Interesting. Does not it defeat the entire purpose of bifields?